# Selenium Web Driver does not work on xvfb

Tags: firefox, selenium, robotframework, xvfb

I want to run my Robot Framework tests which include Selenium2Library keywords on an Ubuntu remote machine so they should be run without a display. At first I just tried to run a simple test and get following result:

```
WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I installed **xvfb** in order the run headless tests and run these lines on remote shell:

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac
export DISPLAY=:10
```

Now i am getting the following error and I can't get rid of it

```
test                                                                  |         FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I checked nearly all questions here about Selenium on xvfb and this specific error.

Since some mentioned about Selenium - Firefox incompability, I tried updating selenium (it is up to date, version 2.46.0), my Firefox was latest and i has not worked. 
Then I tried using an old firefox relase (35.0) which is also not worked

Now I'm trying a solution for this problem and I am almost sure it is about fireofx.
Thanks for your answers and advices

EDIT:
->Runing tests with chrome works just fine

->Also i checked my iptables if there is a rule blocking network to local, it is in default state

Comment: You could run through http://dailychitty.blogspot.de/2014/07/configuring-jenkins-agent-to-run-robot.html and check if you missed anything during installation of xvfb. I had installed it for Centos and it had worked fine for me.

Comment: I tried the run that script bu i did not worked acutally the commands in script were very similar to mine and other steps were same till runing xvfb. I think that tihs issue is not related with Xvfb but cant figure out

Comment: How do you start Firefox in your robot file? Are you trying to pass some special parameters? Does it work if you just use "Open Browser   http://stackoverflow.com/   Firefox"

Comment: @Pekka Exacty how i am calling firefox. Also I am now sure that problem is with firefox since chome opens and takes screenshos without a problem in same test cases that ff gives error.